# How to merge two bins in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cut, bin

I am using pd.cut and binning data. After this step, I am finding the mean of data in each bin and if the difference in the mean between two bins are below a threshold, I want to merge the two bins together.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{ 'col1': 7, 'val': 2},
                   {'col1':   20, 'val': 22},
                   {'col1':  11, 'val': 12},
                   { 'col1': 9, 'val': 13},
                   { 'col1':   14, 'val': 11}])


df['bin1']=pd.cut(df['col1'], 3)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('bin1')['val'].mean())

threshold = 5
```

Output:

```
                   val
bin1    
(6.987, 11.333]     9
(11.333, 15.667]    11
(15.667, 20.0]      22
```

if the difference of mean of val is less than the threshold (5), then i want to merge the bins.

So the new bins now should be:

```
                 
bin1    
(6.987, 15.667]     
(15.667, 20.0]
```

I don't know how to do the last step..
Thank you!

Comment: do the bins have to be consecutive to be merged? what would you want to do if more than than two bins were within the mean of each other, would they all get merged together?

Comment: What if last bin has mean `15`, which is `4` more than the second bin. Would you merge it with the previous two bins?

Comment: @mitoRibo: Yes, the bins need to be consecutive to be merged.

Comment: @QuangHoang:  i compare neighbouring bins. Ofcourse when i combine the bins, the mean would change a bit. But typically the differences in mean between bins i see in my data is either very small or huge. so i would have to choose a threshold accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The common technique to merge consecutive rows is to work on cumsum of negate condition. Here, that would be:

```
blocks = df2['val'].diff().gt(threshold).cumsum()
```

However, since you're working with the index, it's better to just reset it so we can work on columns:

```
df2 = df2.reset_index()
blocks = df2['val'].diff().gt(threshold).cumsum()
df2.groupby(blocks).agg({
    'bin1': lambda x: pd.Interval(x.iloc[0].left, x.iloc[-1].right)
})
```

Output:

```
                bin1
val                 
0    (6.987, 15.667]
1     (15.667, 20.0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. and the fact that i could have never thought of this makes me depressed !! :)